# In PHP MVC, in which part do I interact with an excel document?

Tags: php, excel, model-view-controller, laravel, laravel-4

I'm moving all of my scripts to the laravel framework. I interact heavily with excel documents. I am a little unsure of where to actually do this at. I was initially thinking in the model, but it isn't really a database that I can access with eloquent or anything. definitely not controller or view.

Comment: Would you mind sharing some details about how you interact with the excel files?

Comment: export data from surveymonkey, read the excel file using phpexcel (now using php-excel-reader), and then perform various operations like most common occurrence in X column, top 10 in X column, and so on..

Comment: I strongly suggest taking a look at the [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) library.  You could easily create a [Service Provider](http://laravel.com/docs/ioc#service-providers) in Laravel and use that to integrate it into your project.

Answer (score 0):

an excel document contains bussiness logic. so definetly a Model.

short explenation.

each excel document represents a entity of some sort. on each entity you want to perform the same logic.

Comment: is it even possible to create a model in laravel that doesn't extend eloquent?

Comment: no model ever needs to be extended. a model is always seperate from the framework (maybe a base model for db functionality or something). you only call your model from your controller or pass it to the view.